# SSRS Drill Down Report error - 'Overload Resolution failed - Parameter can not convert from Object to String'

Tags: string, object, reporting-services, parameters, cascading

I am having an error in my Drill Down Report 
(I use cascading parameters for my report, if that helps).

When i use the following grouping in the "Series Groups":

```
=SWITCH(
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Region", Fields!GLRegionWHID.Value,   
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Program Type", Fields!EHRProgramTypeWHID.Value,
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Program", Fields!GLProgramWHID.Value,
Parameters!Scope.Value = "Staff", Fields!PaycomEmployeeWHID.Value
```

)

The following long error message appears:

"An error occurred during local report processing.
 The Group expression for the grouping 'Chart-Report' contains an error: Overload resolution failed because no Public '=' can be called with these arguments: 'Public Shared Operator=(a As String, b As String) As Boolean':
Argument matching parameter 'a' cannot convert from Object() to String"

Anyone, please help!

Comment: Are you sure your parameter VALUE is a string? In most cases the Value would be an integer/ID/Key of some sort and the Label property would be a string as that's what the user sees. Try changing `Parameters!Scope.Value` to `Parameters!Scope.Label`

Comment: I've found what was my problem!  It was the 'scope' setting, where I accidentally selected "allow multiple values". I really meant my Scope to have a drop down option. But it can't select the multiple values in the scope, as it's the Drill Down to one dataset.